# Calling coreftp application with perl

Tags: perl

I am attempting to loop through a set of files and upload to an FTP site using `coreftp`. I need to use core ftp and cannot use `Net::SFTP` or any other module.

When I run this command from CMD prompt, it works perfectly, but as you can see it is only for one file:

```
'"c:\program files\coreftp\coreftp.exe" -s -O -site My_Upload_Site -u //someserver/atextfile.txt -p /directory/'
```

I am requesting assistance on combining the `foreach` loop variable with the command prompt. How can I call the CMD script and replace the `"//someserver/atextfile.txt"` with `$TheInputDir/$FileToUse` from the foreach loop?

```
 foreach $FileToUse(@FilesToUse)  
    {
'"c:\program files\coreftp\coreftp.exe" -s -O -site My_Upload_Site -u //someserver/atextfile.txt -p /directory/'

#once uploaded move the file
    move ("$TheInputDir/$FileToUse", "$TheMoveDir/$FileToUse") or $MailMsg = $MailMsg . "ERROR: Moving files Failed! \n";

    }
```

if there is a better way, I am always open to suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had a great deal of success with PUTTY, specifically, `PSCP`. You can run `PSCP` on the command line, to test it and to make sure that you are calling it correctly. Then, in your script, call it with `system()`, or back ticks, or however you want to. Whether it's better to use SCP or SFTP is a matter of debate, and I don't take sides here. For my purposes, `PSCP` worked very well.

Unfortunately, I don't currently have access to a remote server, or I would write a script to illustrate it. Still, it's easy to use and reliable.

Download: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Usage example: `pscp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt`